Redireccionar a pagina ASP.NET con algun parametro
Como andan todos. Vengo nuevamente a realizarles una consulta. Sigo aprendiendo C# y ASP.NET desde que decidí pasarme de DELPHI a C#. He podido avanzar bastante y aprender muchas cosas nuevas.
Les comento. Estoy desarrollando una simple app web, de productividad tipo EVERNOTE. Algo muy básico, pero me va quedando bastante bonito por suerte!! Ya he realizado varias pruebas y de a poco a medida que voy adquiriendo conocimientos voy agregándoles características.
El problema radica en la autenticación.Estoy utilizando JWTBearer para la misma. Todo iba de maravilla , hasta que decidi separar los proyectos y gestionar los usuarios y la autenticacion en un servicio aparte para modularizar los mismos.
La funcionalidad la tengo implementada, pero no se como realizar algunas cosas, al todavía no conocer en profundidad algunos conceptos.
Me explico. La app de notas,al ingresar al primer ENDPOINT, verifica si el usuario envia algo en el AUTHORIZATION, si el TOKEN no coincide o no existe, se redireccona a la pagina de autenticacion. Que seria el servicio de autenticacion.
Una vez que realizo el logueo del usuario en el servicio y pagina de autenticacion el token se genera, todo perfecto.
Mi problema comienza al querer volver al proyecto original. En si no se como hacerlo. Yo busco capturar el dominio que accede,o pasar un parametro, al servicio de autenticacion ,para que una vez devuelto el token, poder redireccionar devuelta a mi servicio de notas.
ESTE SERIA MI PROYECTO DE NOTAS :
app.MapGet("/", async  (HttpContext context) => {
    
    
    if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
        await context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/dsnotes.html"); //Entrega del archivo estatico
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ingreso no autorizado , redireccion");
        context.Response.Redirect("http://100.100.0.100:5072"); // redireccion a autenticacion
    }

});

Una vez que realizo la redireccion a la ip donde se encuentra el proyecto de autenticacion corriendo en ese puerto(distinto al proyecto principal). No se como volver de vuelta al servicio original con el token ya en memoria en el frontend.
El asunto es que guardarlo en el localstorage o sessionStorage, se borra al cambiar el dominio de la pagina.
Obviamente estoy quieriendolo realizar de esta forma, para poder reutilizar mi servicio de autenticacion para otros proyectos. Porque podria redireccionar manualmente, pero no es lo que busco. Mi idea seria pasar algun parametro en la redireccion, y que el servicio de autenticacion detecte que servicio realizo o se conecto, y de ahi reenviar al usuario al servicio correcto.
Pero no sabria de que forma hacerlo o como hacerlo, o si es posible pasar un parametro en la solicitud GET o en una redireccion (deberia leer un poco mas sobre HTTP en este caso.)
ESTOS SERIAN LOS ENDPOINTS DEL PROYECTO DE AUTENTICACION :
    app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) => { // redireccion de la raiz
        
        context.Response.Redirect("/Sda/Authentication/");
    });
    
//Entrega del archivo estatico login.html
    app.MapGet("/Sda/Authentication/", async (HttpContext context) => await context.Response.SendFileAsync("wwwroot/login.html")); 
    
    //Endpoint de autenticacion que recibe los datos del usuario.
    app.MapPost("/Sda/Authentication", (HttpContext context , AccountLoginReceived instance) => {
        
        if (Validations.AccountLoginValidation(instance)) 
        {
            if (AccountDatabase.AccountLogin(instance)!= null)  // se procede a la generacion del token de acceso a servicios
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(AccountDatabase.AccountLogin(instance).SDAEmail);
                return Results.Ok(LoginAuthentication.GenerateToken(AccountDatabase.AccountLogin(instance)));
            } else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usuario o contraseña invalidos");
                return Results.BadRequest("Usuario o contraseña invalidos");
            }
            
           
        }  
        return Results.BadRequest("Usuario o contraseña invalidos");
    
    }); 

PIDO PERDON POR MI CODIGO, Obviamente debe ser una porqueria xD. Pero de ahi yo quisiera poder redireccionar de vuelta hacia mi proyecto original, junto con el token y que el mismo se persista.

despues de tener un dia complicado, me he ido a descansar. Y al otro dia, me he tomado mi tiempo, comido unos buenos sanguches con cafe y con la cabeza mas limpia me he puesto a buscar y leer. Creo que he podido poder relacionar a menos de momento y de forma basica mis servicios.
Antes de hacer la redireccion, vi que es posible crear una Cokkie, y enviarla en la redireccion : lo he comprobado y ahora el valor se encuentra disponible en la pagina de login del servicio de autenticacion :
 context.Response.Cookies.Append("sv", "dsnotes");
 context.Response.Redirect("http://100.100.0.100:5072");

Creo que de momento esto me es suficiente como para que el servicio identifique quien realizo la peticion y ya podria redireccionar nuevamente. A menos por ahora me es suficiente.
A medida que vaya avanzando seguramente mejorare mi codigo horrible jaja. Muchas gracias.
